# How to make a NOR between 2 vectors in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two vectors :

```
predictions = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] 
labels      = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

and I need as an output (using python) the `true negatives - NOR` of these two vectors.

```
output      = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

I tried with this command but it throw an error :

```py
print not(predictions & labels)

>>>TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'list'
```

What is the correct syntax / command to do such a simple thing ?

Comment: I think your output shows the logical NOR of the two lists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native python does not support vector operation. You have to nand individual element

```
>>> [int(not (p & l)) for p, l in zip(predictions, labels)]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Off -course if you are using numpy, you can achieve what you are envisaging

```
>>> np.logical_not(np.logical_and(predictions, labels)).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1])
```

It is worth noting that your output is not Nand but actually Nor, so you have to apply the operations accordingly

```
>>> np.logical_not(np.logical_or(predictions, labels)).astype(int)
array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks, i edited my question with the appropriate output naming.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3):

Here You have to iterate to every item in the list

```
 c=[int(not i&j) for i,j in zip(predictions,labels)]
```

The operator & is not defined for operands of type list.
The operator not will return True if len(list>0), if the list is empty it will return false.
Also you need to cast booleans to ints to achieve the required result.

Answer (score 0):

With [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) and the [operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module:

```
from operator import eq,and_,or_,xor
from itertools import imap
predictions = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1] 
labels      = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
#Logical AND
print [int(e) for e in imap(and_,predictions,labels)]
#Logical NAND
print [int(not e) for e in imap(and_,predictions,labels)]
#Logical OR
print [int(e) for e in imap(or_,predictions,labels)]
#Logical NOR
print [int(not e) for e in imap(or_,predictions,labels)]
#Logical XOR
print [int(e) for e in imap(xor,predictions,labels)]
#Logical not XOR
print [int(not e) for e in imap(xor,predictions,labels)]
```